# Can I test deleteSMS and deleteContacts in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms

Firstly I asked sorry if this is a stupid question. but I have a doubt about it but I cannot find any soultions yet, so I asked here.

Can I test deleteSMS and deleteContacts in android emulator other than real device?

Because, it can be able to send sms from one emulator to another emulator.  Can anyone tell it can  or cannot and what is the reason if can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, no issues. :) i think you should ask how to delete, instead of can we delete.
anyways go ahead it will work..
below is the code and the URi which can be used for the above purpose.

```
ContentResolver cr = _context.getContentResolver();

  Uri inbox = Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" );
Cursor cursor = cr.query(
    inbox,
    new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "body" },
    null,
    null,
    null);do {        
    String body = cursor.getString( 2 );            
    long thread_id = cursor.getLong( 1 );
    Uri thread = Uri.parse( "content://sms/conversations/" + thread_id );
    cr.delete( thread, null, null );
    count++;

} while ( cursor.moveToNext() );
```

Comment: thanks Ankit, i got confused bcz i got a runtime exception when try to delete sms from emulator. now i think the code may be have some issue. is uri path is common for both case                                   Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms")

Comment: I have modified my Answer, URi is "Content://sms/inbox", you can delete the message from conversation, first get ThreadID from Uri mentioned above,and then delete from conversation "content://sms/conversation/"+ thred ID

Comment: accept answer if it helped you. there is one check sign with the answer